# Mouse grips: How much will I benefit from using a claw or fingertip grip over a palm grip, and is it worth the additional fatigue?

Tags: mouse

I've been reading about several different ways to use a mouse for gaming, including palm, claw, and fingertip grips.  I understand that the claw and fingertip grips allow for more precise movement and faster button presses than the palm grip, but how much of a difference in game-play performance can I expect, as measured by K/D ratios or other similar metrics?  Is this worth the additional fatigue?

Comment: What has happened to me is that my mid-finger knuckles have locked up, making it difficult to press the buttons, like a hyper-extension cramp. I must be a palmer. I use a Deathadder. The further side mouse button (A.K.A. XButton2/mouse5) is hard to press (without risk of hitting the closer) without palming. It seems that the top of my mouse has been worn down, so I have to be between palming and fingertipping.

Comment: Hmmm, the strange thing about this is that there is still another difference in gripping, you could use your left mouse button with your trigger finger and your middle finger on the right. Or you could use the ring finger on the scroller and ring finger on the right.

Comment: before I saw this question, i never thought about it, but now I realize that I've naturally evolved to a fingertip grip, just felt natural to me.

Comment: Anecdotally, I use a fingertip grip I adopted without conscious effort from years of using relatively small mice, e.g. Logitech Mini Optical, Logitech VX Nano. Contacting a mouse with my palm feels very strange to me. I notice no hand fatigue except for occasional soreness in my middle finger joint during days of heavy mouse wheel usage. (I don't know how this grip affects my mousing performance.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I (being a great Razer fan) looked this question up on the Razer website. [THIS](http://www.razerzone.com/mouseguide/ergonomic/advantage) is what I found.

In a nutshell:

**Advantages of the palm grip:** the user is able to move the mouse at higher speeds, and achieve higher Inches Per Second (IPS) ratings. The palm grip is also considered one of the most comfortable grip styles for gaming where the gamer is able to continue playing for extended hours without experiencing fatigue.

**Disadvantages of the palm grip:** in order to keep the point of contact with their palm and the back of the mouse intact, users will find it difficult to perform fine tuning with their fingers.

**Advantages of the claw grip:** Precise and quick movement, fast access to the 4th and 5th mouse button.

**Disadvantages of the claw grip:**  Does not feel natural, your hand gets tired faster.

**Advantages of the fingertip grip:** Same as claw grip but with more agility.

**Disadvantages of the fingertip grip:**  Most hand fatigue of any technique hardest one to learn.

Personally I started off using the claw grip method on a fingertip designed mouse and after I got used to the claw grip I switched to the fingertip grip. This probably took me around 2 weeks.

I also would like to add that if you don't use a high sensitivity setting for example under 6/10 I would suggest the palm grip, otherwise you would have to move your wrist while turning around and that is not the most enjoyable thing to do with fingertip grip. I use a sensitivity of 9 so I only need to move my mouse for 1 or 2 inches and I'm across the screen and turned 2 circles.

Comment: It depends on your mouse aswell IMO, I'm using the palmgrip on the Cyborg Rat 9 mouse, and because the mouse allows for alot of customization I can reach the side buttons without a problem.

Comment: this is true but as you can see on the website i provided the difference in the differed grips is the speed and accuracy of the movement not the actual grip.

Comment: I know, but the Razers have had a standard setup, so while it is true for most mouses that the accuracy is less, it is not for all. Btw maybe you can add this paragraph in your awnser aswell : The palm grip is also considered one of the most comfortable grip styles for gaming where the gamer is able to continue playing for extended hours without experiencing fatigue.